# How Import Esri .sd (Service Definition) file into a file geodatabase without publishing it up to Portal

Tags: arcgis-pro, service-definition

I have received bunch of Service Definition files `.sd` from a client and I need to import some data from them into a File Geodatabase. Is there any way that I open them in ArcGIS Pro and import feature classes in FGDB?

Comment: While it's possible that a service definition could contain data, that's usually an occasion of an error on the part of the publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SD files are just plain ZIP files. So you can unzip them and you will find the data there if the service is not referencing data from some internal drive of your customer.

Comment: Technically they've been zipped using 7zip which Windows can struggle with reading/unzipping. If you run into trouble unzipping with the windows default, download 7zip to extract.